# How to use a Windows Personal User Certificates in C# to sign an arbitrary string

Tags: c#, cryptography

I would like to write a small program that sign a string with a Windows Personal User Certificate.

I found that `CAPICOM` was a solution, but it now a legacy and only a 32bit compatible solution.

Ideally I would like something like:

```
 digest = sign(string, 'myWindowsCertificate');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use the `System.Security.Cryptography`.

Let's imagine you want to sign with a `WISeKey` key present in your Store:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            foreach (var cert in store.Certificates)
            {
                string desc = cert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, true);
                if (desc.Contains("WISeKey"))
                {
                    RSA pk = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();                    
                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello World ... !");
                    byte[] signature = pk.SignData(buffer, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
                    System.Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(signature));                  

                    break;
                }                
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```